# MAGENTO Where do I find ALL invoice and order templates in magento?

Tags: email, templates, magento, invoice

I need to edit the invoices that are generated in the magento backend. They look completely different from those sent after transactions. I need to know where to find the templates for the backend emails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The emails sent from the backend are generated based on the email templates that you find if you go to *System* => *Transaction Emails*. Depending on you installation you'll probably find a lot of templates there. Which template is used is configured in *System* => *Configuration* => *Sales Emails (in the SALES section)*.

If you dig into the email template, you'll find references to design templates. The *invoice email template* contains the following line, for example:

```
 {{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

This references to a template that can be found in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/invoice/items.php

Note that the /base/default/ part of the path obove might be different if you've installed a design theme that overwrites this template.

So, depending on what you want to change, you'll have to change either the email template (using the backend) or referenced templates using a code editor.

Comment: Great stuff, Aufroller!. appreciate it..